# Excel 2013: Conditional Formatting changes after Query has run

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have conditional formatting on Columns A to N. Columns F to N are updated every time I open the spreadsheet as it pulls info from a SQL script. The problem I'm having is the following:

My conditional formatting is meant to look like this:

[image]

However once I close and re-open, it looks like this:

[image]

When I went into the parameters, I saw Excel is actually changing my range from `=$A$4:$N$119` to `=$A$4:$E$119` after the query has run.  Is there any way to get Conditional Formatting to apply its rules after a query has been run? I've tried searching online for this but I'm not having much luck.

Comment: Do you consider VBA solution?

Comment: I did - The spreadsheet is already using VBA to bring up a pop-up, then do a refresh and then remove certain rows based on values, but with my limited VBA knowledge I wasn't 100% sure how to apply conditional formatting inside all of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't really find an answer for this but got a workaround - pivoted the query results instead and just applied conditional formatting on the pivot.